# Compare function in bubble sort c++

Tags: c++, compare, bubble-sort

Hi i need to implement compare function inside bubble sort algorithm but i have no idea how to do this.

Compare function:

```
int compareNumbers(const void *a, const void  *b)
{
    object *A = (object *)a;
    object *B = (object *)b;
    if(A->number > B->number)
        return 1;
    else if(A->number < B->number)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

and bubble sort:

```
void bubble_sort(object tab[],int size_tab)
{
object temp;
for(int i=1; i<size_tab; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<size_tab - i; j++)
    {
        if(tab[j].number > tab[j+1].number)
        {               
            temp = tab[j];
            tab[j] = tab[j+1];
            tab[j+1] = temp;
        }

    }   
}
```

I'm not sure if when I want to implement bubble sort, the line:

```
if(tab[j].number > tab[j+1].number)
```

should disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like

```
bool compareNumbers(const void* a, const void* b) {
    object* A = (object*) a;
    object* B = (object*) b;
    if (A->number <= B->number) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then change bubbleSort params in order to look like

```
void bubbleSort(object tab[], int size_tab, 
                bool(comparator*)(const void*, const void*))
```

Now you can pass the pointer to `compareNumbers` function as third argument of `bubbleSort` function:

```
bubbleSort(a, n, &compareNumbers);
```

and use it in `bubbleSort`'s implemetntation:

```
void bubbleSort(object tab[], int size_tab, 
                bool(comparator*)(const void*, const void*)) {
    object temp;
    for (int i = 1; i < size_tab; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size_tab - i; j++) {
            if (comparator(tab + j, tab + j + 1)) {               
                temp = tab[j];
                tab[j] = tab[j+1];
                tab[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **test.cpp:53:57: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token**
**test.cpp:53:57: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token**
**test.cpp:53:57: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token**
@Anton this is the output i get when compilating.

Comment: whoops, forgot closing brace in `if` statement. Edited and fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the `compareNumbers` that you have, the line

```
if(tab[j].number > tab[j+1].number)
```

should become

```
if(compareNumbers(&tab[j],&tab[j+1]) == 1)
```

I would also recommend changing `compareNumbers` to:

```
int compareNumbers(const object *a, const object *b)
{
    if(a->number > b->number)
        return 1;
    else if(a->number < b->number)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

or even better yet, using [references](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html).

---

To give you an idea of a C++11 way to do this:

```
template <class T>
void bubble_sort( T tab[], size_t tab_size, std::function<bool(const T&,const T&)> Comp )
{
    if ( !tab || tab_size < 2 ) return;
    for ( size_t i=1; i<tab_size; ++i )
    for ( size_t j=0; j<tab_size-i; ++j )
        if (Comp(tab[j],tab[j+1])) 
            std::swap(tab[j],tab[j+1]);
}
```

and then call with

```
bubble_sort( tab, 42, []( const object& a, const object& b )->bool {return a.number < b.number;} );
bubble_sort( tab, 42, []( const object& a, const object& b )->bool {return a.letter < b.letter;} );
```

Comment: And do i have to add function arguments to bubble sort? And how can i modify bubble sort to be able to implement two different compare functions f.e. compareNumbers and compare Letters.

Comment: Not as long as you compare the `number` member only, however you should make sure that `compareNumbers` is declared before `bubbleSort`. If you want to be able to select which member to compare (number or letter), then there are different things you can do, but that's another question.

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far. But could you give me a hint how to do this. I think i can't ask another question (90 min block) and i would appreciate some more information.

Comment: Have a look at Anton's solution for an example of how to pass pointers to functions. Be aware though that this is closer to C than C++. There are better, cleaner ways to do this in C++ (ie using references, function objects or even lambda functions).

Comment: @Sh3ljohn - You can actually turn the compare func into a one-liner. You don't need to return -1, 0 or 1 - you simply need to return <0, ==0 and >0. With this in mind, you can trim the body down to: `return a->number - b->number;` to sort in the oppoiste direction, you simply reverse the terms - `return b->number - a->number;`

Comment: @enhzflep You can also use `std::sort` and turn the entire thing into a one-liner, but that's not the question. :) His comparison function is implemented  `strcmp`-style, which is a choice like another, there is no reason to change this a priori.